# Maven Installation has runtime as JRE instead of JDK

Tags: java, maven

I have downloaded Maven in my system and provided the path setting.

when I run `mvn -version`

```
Apache Maven 3.6.3 (cecedd343002696d0abb50b32b541b8a6ba2883f)
Maven home: C:\apache-maven-3.6.3\bin\..
Java version: 1.8.0_251, vendor: Oracle Corporation, runtime: **C:\Program Files\Java\jre1.8.0_251**
Default locale: en_US, platform encoding: Cp1252
OS name: "windows 10", version: "10.0", arch: "amd64", family: "windows"
```

The runtime should have the JDk but It is showing jre.

In the environment path -
USER Variable -

1. `JAVA_HOME` - `C:\Program Files\Java\jdk1.8.0_251`
2. `MAVEN_HOME` - `C:\apache-maven-3.6.3`

System Variable -

1. path - `C:\apache-maven-3.6.3\bin`

When I run - `mvn`

```
[INFO] Scanning for projects...
[INFO] ------------------------------------------------------------------------
[INFO] BUILD FAILURE
[INFO] ------------------------------------------------------------------------
[INFO] Total time:  0.132 s
[INFO] Finished at: 2020-07-13T15:45:37+05:30
[INFO] ------------------------------------------------------------------------
[ERROR] No goals have been specified for this build. You must specify a valid lifecycle phase or a goal in the format <plugin-prefix>:<goal> or <plugin-group-id>:<plugin-artifact-id>[:<plugin-version>]:<goal>. Available lifecycle phases are: validate, initialize, generate-sources, process-sources, generate-resources, process-resources, compile, process-classes, generate-test-sources, process-test-sources, generate-test-resources, process-test-resources, test-compile, process-test-classes, test, prepare-package, package, pre-integration-test, integration-test, post-integration-test, verify, install, deploy, pre-clean, clean, post-clean, pre-site, site, post-site, site-deploy. -> [Help 1]
[ERROR]
[ERROR] To see the full stack trace of the errors, re-run Maven with the -e switch.
[ERROR] Re-run Maven using the -X switch to enable full debug logging.
[ERROR]
[ERROR] For more information about the errors and possible solutions, please read the following articles:
[ERROR] [Help 1] http://cwiki.apache.org/confluence/display/MAVEN/NoGoalSpecifiedException
```

running mvn package also gives me below error -

```
 [INFO] Scanning for projects...
    [INFO] ------------------------------------------------------------------------
    [INFO] BUILD FAILURE
    [INFO] ------------------------------------------------------------------------
    [INFO] Total time:  0.146 s
    [INFO] Finished at: 2020-07-13T22:44:10+05:30
    [INFO] ------------------------------------------------------------------------
    [ERROR] The goal you specified requires a project to execute but there is no POM in this directory (C:\Users\A7704913). Please verify you invoked Maven from the correct directory. -> [Help 1]
    [ERROR]
    [ERROR] To see the full stack trace of the errors, re-run Maven with the -e switch.
    [ERROR] Re-run Maven using the -X switch to enable full debug logging.
    [ERROR]
    [ERROR] For more information about the errors and possible solutions, please read the following articles:
    [ERROR] [Help 1] http://cwiki.apache.org/confluence/display/MAVEN/MissingProjectException
```

How Can I do the runtime to be a JDK not JRE.

Comment: Just try `mvn package` instead of `mvn` only.

Comment: Which Java is on your PATH?

Comment: @JFMeier C:\Program Files\Java\jdk1.8.0_251 & C:\Program Files\Java\jre1.8.0_251...I have two folders in my JAVA folder jdk & Jre

Comment: Remove the JRE from your PATH variable.

Comment: I have just added JDK in the PATH variable @JF Meier

Comment: @khmarbaise I tried to run the mvn package it also gives me error

Comment: Than you you should change into a directory where a `pom.xm` can be found to build a Maven project...

Comment: okay but my runtime is showing "Java version: 1.8.0_251, vendor: Oracle Corporation, runtime: **C:\Program Files\Java\jre1.8.0_251**" , How can I change this to JDK? @khmarbaise

Comment: Is this the value of your `JAVA_HOME` If yes you have to install a JDK and set JAVA_HOME accordingly.

Comment: Thanks @khmarbaise I installed maven in the project directory where my pom.xm is also there so the problem is solved. Thanks again :)