# Maven is using wrong java version

Tags: java, maven, centos

I am trying to build a maven project on centOS 8. I want maven to use Java version 15. When I run `mvn package` I get the following error:

```
Failed to execute goal org.apache.maven.plugins:maven-compiler-plugin:3.8.1:compile 
(default-compile) on project systembrett-backend: Fatal error compiling: invalid target release: 15 -> [Help 1]
```

So I suspect that maven is using the wrong Java version, because when i do `mvn package -X` for debug logs it start with:

```
Apache Maven 3.5.4 (Red Hat 3.5.4-5)
Maven home: /usr/share/maven
Java version: 1.8.0_275, vendor: Red Hat, Inc., runtime: /usr/lib/jvm/java-1.8.0-openjdk-1.8.0.275.b01-1.el8_3.x86_64/jre
Default locale: en_US, platform encoding: UTF-8
OS name: "linux", version: "4.18.0-240.1.1.el8_3.x86_64", arch: "amd64", family: "unix"
```

so it looks like, maven is using Java version 1.8.
But `mvn -version` says:

```
Apache Maven 3.5.4 (Red Hat 3.5.4-5)
Maven home: /usr/share/maven
Java version: 15.0.2, vendor: AdoptOpenJDK, runtime: /opt/jdk-15.0.2+7
Default locale: en_US, platform encoding: UTF-8
OS name: "linux", version: "4.18.0-240.1.1.el8_3.x86_64", arch: "amd64", family: "unix"
```

`JAVA_HOME` is `/opt/jdk-15.0.2+7` and `PATH` is `/opt/jdk-15.0.2+7/bin:/home/username/.local/bin:/home/username/bin:/usr/local/bin:/usr/bin:/usr/local/sbin:/usr/sbin`.

I thought maven is choosing the java version by checking `JAVA_HOME`, but apparently it is using an other version for the build. Does anyone know how to tell maven the correct version?
Thanks!

Comment: Maybe your pom.xml is overriding [maven-compiler-plugin configuration](https://maven.apache.org/plugins/maven-compiler-plugin/examples/compile-using-different-jdk.html)?

Answer (score 8, accepted):

Following is a list of steps I use to troubleshoot this kind of issues:

1. Linux usually works with `alternatives` to ensure proper default Java environment is used. Similar to:

```sh
$ alternatives --config java

There are 2 programs which provide 'java'.

  Selection    Command
-----------------------------------------------
 + 1           java-1.7.0-openjdk.x86_64 (/usr/lib/jvm/java-1.7.0-openjdk-1.7.0.191-2.6.15.4.el7_5.x86_64/jre/bin/java)
*  2           java-1.8.0-openjdk.x86_64 (/usr/lib/jvm/java-1.8.0-openjdk-1.8.0.181-3.b13.el7_5.x86_64/jre/bin/java)
```

Try also for `javac` as it may not be configured the same way:

```sh
$ alternatives --config javac
```

2. For your `maven` instance, `JAVA_HOME` should be enough.

Your output of `mvn -version` testifies that you have configured it correctly. Remove your Java from your `PATH` to ensure `JAVA_HOME` and `mvn` will find the correct one.

1. The `pom.xml` can also configure the required compiler, similar to:

```xml
<properties>
    <maven.compiler.source>1.8</maven.compiler.source>
    <maven.compiler.target>1.8</maven.compiler.target>
</properties>
```

2. Another thing may be that you're not using the same ENV (different terminals may not have the same environment variables exported - I presume you being on CentOS, you already encountered this). You have to exit the terminal and get back in to allow the default variables to take effect.

You encounter this usually when different JRE vs JDK are used ( [more: maven installation has runtime as JRE instead of JDK](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/62874028/maven-installation-has-runtime-as-jre-instead-of-jdk) )

Comment: Thank you! Is there any way to automate alternatives selection when we install a new JDK?

Comment: Each distro will have different conventions. The distro package (e.g. `.rpm`, `.deb` etc) is responsible for managing the alternatives. The `alternatives` can be configured at the `user` level too, using a Configuration Management framework or manually. Feel free to raise another stackoverflow question with the exact need, and we can work on that.

Answer (score 3):

I had the same issue on RHEL 9.1. The solution was to look at `/etc/java/maven.conf` and set the correct `JAVA_HOME` here in this file.

In other words, you can add just the single line similar to this to that `maven.conf` file:

```
JAVA_HOME=/usr/lib/jvm/java-17-openjdk
```

and you should be good.

Comment: As it’s currently written, your answer is unclear. Please [edit] to add additional details that will help others understand how this addresses the question asked. You can find more information on how to write good answers [in the help center](/help/how-to-answer).

Comment: I edited my `/etc/java/maven.conf` to use `/usr/lib/jvm/jre` so that it can work when changing java version with `alternatives --config java`. If the path was instead set to `/usr/lib/jvm/jre-openjdk` then it would need to be updated with `alternatives --config java_sdk_openjdk`

Answer (score 0):

Additionally from checking environment variable `JAVA_HOME`, file `.m2/settings.xml` on your home directory, and files `/etc/java/maven.conf` and `$MAVEN_HOME/conf/maven.conf` for JVM paths, there is a pretty obscure way to configure maven JVM user-wide.

You can define a file `.mavenrc` on your home directory
Just put  `JAVA_HOME=<jdk path as in JAVA_HOME>` on `.mavenrc` and maven will automatically use that JDK.

If your maven is reverting to some wrong JVM you can check if `~/.mavenrc` exists and if the unwanted JVM path is defined there.